# INSERT INTO...SELECT...WHERE with null if condition fails

Tags: sqlite, insert-select

I'm attempting to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO `File` (`Name`, `Owner`) 
SELECT @File, `Users`.Id
FROM `Users`
WHERE `Users`.`Name` = @UserName
```

However, if there is no match in the Users table, I would like it to still insert the file but with a null value. So like performing a LEFT JOIN on the Users table with ON replacing the WHERE. But I can't just use a LEFT JOIN because I don't have a table to join it to. Can anyone help me out in how I could do this without breaking it into two separate queries?

This is specifically for SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO `File` (`Name`, `Owner`) 
SELECT @File, `Users`.Id
FROM (SELECT @UserName as Name) notable
left join `Users` on `Users`.`Name` = notable.Name
```

Comment: Not quite how I would like it, but it works. I wish there was a way to do this without a subquery, but if it works it works.